# List giving an empty values upto penultimate cell

Tags: r, list, knn

following is the code i am trying to run.The main objective is to run the model for different K values then after calculate the accuracies in order to choose the best K value.

so i thought of using for loop where every model.Result and the respective accuracy is stored in lists.,then after is sent out with respective k values..
but the thing is for the following code...the list isnt having any values from 1:29 and there is predicted values for 30..

```
    k = 1:30
for(l in k){
    
  pre[[l]] = knn(train_dataset,test_dataset,cl = labels_train, k = l)
  
}
```

output :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s4hs.png)

can someone help me out with this....like why the list is coming like that and what should be done in order to get the correct result..and why so..?

Comment: Where is your definition of `pre` and why not using `lapply(1:30, function (l) return(knn(train_dataset,test_dataset,cl = labels_train, k = l)))`

Comment: Please include a call to `library` in the script, there are many packages with a function `knn`. Which one are you using?

Comment: @tacoman pre is the empty list i have initiated before with the code line pre = list()..iam not using it because i dont know about it.Will try now and What is wrong with the above line then?
i have initiated an empty list and then after storing models with for loop..why itsnt this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, with the models fit using the code in [tacoman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252565/list-giving-an-empty-values-upto-penultimate-cell#comment120627024_68252565).

```
library(class)

set.seed(1)  # Make the results reproducible
knn_list <- lapply(1:30, function(l){
  knn(train_dataset, test_dataset, cl = labels_train, k = l)
})

ok <- sapply(knn_list, '==', labels_test)
acc <- colMeans(ok)

which(acc == max(acc))
plot(acc, type = "b")
```

---

The `for` loop in the question can also be run, as long as the results list is created beforehand. The results are identical.

```
set.seed(1)  # Make the results reproducible
k <- 1:30
pre <- vector("list", length = 30)
for(l in k){
  pre[[l]] <- knn(train_dataset, test_dataset, cl = labels_train, k = l)
}

identical(pre, knn_list)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

### Example data

```
set.seed(2021)
n <- nrow(iris)
i <- sample(n, 0.7*n)
train_dataset <- iris[i, -5]
test_dataset <- iris[-i, -5]
labels_train <- iris[i, 5]
labels_test <- iris[-i, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you @Rui Barradas...But what exactly is wrong with my code?
iam using the class library for KNN function.Initiated an empty list and then after storing the models in the list with the help of a for loop...why it isnt this working?

Comment: @Yagami_Light Have you created `pre <- vector("list", length = 30)` before running the `for` loop?

Comment: No @Rui barradas...I have written this pre = list( )